# Upgrade Kotlin from 1.0.2 - 1.0.3: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method provideInjectedData$app_compileDebugKotlin()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso, dagger-2

I have a Kotlin Espresso Dagger2 small project. Works well when I use Kotlin 1.0.2. After migrated to Kotlin 1.0.3, when running the Espresso instrumental test (on MainActivityTest), it error as above.

My Dagger2 TestModule is as below

```
@Module
open class ApplicationTestModule(protected val mApplication: Application) {

    @Provides
    internal fun provideApplication(): Application {
        return mApplication
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    internal fun provideInjectedData(): InjectedData {
        return mock(InjectedData::class.java)
    }
}
```

The dagger2 generated ApplicationTestModule for the InjectedData is as below

```
package com.elyeproj.kotlinespressomock;

import dagger.internal.Factory;
import dagger.internal.Preconditions;
import javax.annotation.Generated;

@Generated(
  value = "dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor",
  comments = "https://google.github.io/dagger"
)
public final class ApplicationTestModule_ProvideInjectedData$app_compileDebugKotlinFactory
    implements Factory<InjectedData> {
  private final ApplicationTestModule module;

  public ApplicationTestModule_ProvideInjectedData$app_compileDebugKotlinFactory(
      ApplicationTestModule module) {
    assert module != null;
    this.module = module;
  }

  @Override
  public InjectedData get() {
    return Preconditions.checkNotNull(
        module.provideInjectedData$app_compileDebugKotlin(),
        "Cannot return null from a non-@Nullable @Provides method");
  }

  public static Factory<InjectedData> create(ApplicationTestModule module) {
    return new ApplicationTestModule_ProvideInjectedData$app_compileDebugKotlinFactory(module);
  }
}
```

Where the `provideInjectedData$app_compileDebugKotlin()` is Cannot Resolve by AndroidStudio. The test run fails.

I reverify that when using Kotlin 1.0.2 (1.0.1-2), the above function also exist also Cannot Resolve by AndroidStudio. But the test still run.

Is this a Kotlin or Dagger issue? How could I resolve this?

To duplicate the problem, the code could be found in https://github.com/elye/kotlinespressomock. Just change the `ext.KOTLIN_VERSION = '1.0.1-2'` to `ext.KOTLIN_VERSION = '1.0.3'` and run the `MainActivityTest` in AndroidTest.

Comment: I've faced this type of problem myself, and I think it's connected to the `internal` visibility on your methods. If you make them public, the issue may be resolved. But I'm also quite interested in knowing what's the root cause.

Comment: Thanks @AndroidEx! That solve the problem. Ya, hopefully someone from Dagger could provide the insight.